# DataContext is missing properties in where statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Could some tell me why I have no properties in my where statements after using a select statement for e.g.

```
db.Select(x => x.Lft).Where(x => x.DepartmentId == id); 
// missing properties in the where clause
```

And could you help me correct my code to implement it please leave me an example of what to do to implement this thanks

Classes:

```
public class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public long DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a name for the departments.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid url for the department.")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public int Lft { get; set; }
    public int Rgt { get; set; }
    public bool MenuItem { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

my DataContext class

```
internal class DepartmentsTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Department>
{
    public DepartmentsTypeConfiguration()
    {
        Property(department => department.DepartmentId)
            .HasColumnName("DepartmentId")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(databaseGeneratedOption: DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(department => department.Name)
            .HasColumnName("Name")
            .IsRequired();

        HasKey(key => key.DepartmentId)
            .HasMany(x => x.Products)
            .WithRequired(x => x.Department)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);            
    }
}


public class LeapFrogDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductSpecification> ProductSpecifications {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Specification> Specifications { get; set; }
    /**/
    static LeapFrogDataContext()
        //: base("name=LeapFrogDataConnection")
    {
        //Database.SetInitializer(new LeapFrogInitializer());
        //Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<LeapFrogDataContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DepartmentsTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProductsTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SpecificationsTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProductSpecificationsTypeConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`db.Select(x => x.Lft)` returns a list of `int` so in the `where` clause you will not access any property.

I guess you may switch `select` and `where` to achieve what you want. Assume `db` is the actual `context`.

```
db.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == id).Select(x => x.Lft)
```

That's a bit weird. Normally it should look like

```
db.context.Departments.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == id).Select(x => x.Lft)
```